# Emacs: Find text starting with a word and finishin with another word on the same line

Tags: regex, search, emacs

I want a command to find text from `foo` through `bar`, on the same line. For example:

```
hello foo some text here bar
goodbye foo some other text here bar
```

For each line, I want to find the text starting with `foo` and ending with the end of `bar`.

In Vim it would be something like `/foo.*bar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a `isearch-forward-regexp` by typing <kbd>C-M-s</kbd>`foo.*bar`

Further help may be found in the [emacs documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Search.html.)

Answer (score 0):

With the cursor on `foo`, type <kbd>C-s</kbd> to initiate `i-search-forward` then hit <kbd>C-w</kbd> 4 times to expand the search term to cover the next 4 words, or hit <kbd>M-s C-e</kbd> to include the rest of the line in the search term.